# Does a tensor product of Fock spaces specify the order of operators?

Tags: hilbert-space, conventions, notation, grassmann-numbers

Suppose I have 2 fermionic Fock spaces $A$ and $B$ with states denoted as $|n\rangle_A$ and $|m\rangle_B$, where $n$ and $m$ are quantum numbers specifying the occupation numbers in the single particle states. As Fock space basis states I use some specified order of creation operators.

$$|n\rangle_A = \prod_k (c_{k,A}^\dagger)^{n_k} |0\rangle_A\\
|m\rangle_B = \prod_k (c_{k,B}^\dagger)^{m_k} |0\rangle_B$$

Here, $n_k$ and $m_k$ are the occupation numbers of the single particle state $k$ in the manybody state $n$ and $m$, respecitvely.

I now want to take the tensor product of both spaces

$$|n\rangle_A \otimes |m\rangle_B$$

and use it as space for some further calculations. Does the notation of $|n\rangle_A \otimes |m\rangle_B$ say anything about the order of creation operators in the new basis? More specifically, does this notation imply that the creators of space $A$ come to the left of the creators of space $B$, or must I specify the order myself in order for this construct to be usable?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the fermionic creation operators anti-commute even if they act on different fock spaces. Don't they?

Comment: You are quite right, I neglected to read that these were fermionic operators... Apologies!